# viewcontroller type does not have member named button0 tic tac toe

Tags: swift

right so im tryna make a 2d array for a tic tac toe game and get the viewcontrller does not have member named:button0, why do i get the error for this when im trying to create this array

```
@IBOutlet weak var button0: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button3: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button4: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button5: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button6: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button7: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button8: UIButton!
let buttons = [
        [button0,button1,button2], //error comes from button0
        [button3,button4,button5],
        [button6,button7,button8]
    ]
```

Comment: does the error you see come from that `let` line?  or if not, can you show the code where the error line appears?

Comment: it comes from button0

Answer (score 0):

Just cast your **btnArray** as `UIButton` as below

```
var btnArray: [[UIButton]] = [
        [button0, button1, button2],
        [button3, button4, button5],
        [button6, button7, button8]
    ]
```

Comment: it's not an array of UIButton, it is an array of UIButton arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the class members in the initialization phase what you should do is assigning the value in viewDidLoad:

```
@IBOutlet weak var button0: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button3: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button4: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button5: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button6: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button7: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button8: UIButton!
var buttons = [[UIButton]]()

override func viewDidLoad() {

    buttons = [
        [button0,button1,button2],
        [button3,button4,button5],
        [button6,button7,button8]
    ]

}
```